# How to add extra attributes to mongoose js model while its referenced in other model (Mongoose js relationships)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose js and in general to NODE JS.
In My application there are two models as follows

**Test Case Schema**

```
var TestCaseSchema = new Schema({
    description: String,
    expected: String,
    actual: String,
    result: String,
    createdAt: {type:Date},
    updatedAt: {type:Date, default: Date.now()},
});
```

And

**Test Plan Schema** as follows

```
var TestPlanSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    createdBy: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    testCases: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'TestCase'}],
    result: String,
});
```

As you can see Test case schema is referred by Test Plan schema

> testCases: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'TestCase'}]

**Question:**
Is there an easy way to store the test case result in Test Plan. ( I do not want to store the results against the test case model as one test case can exists in multiple test cases and this can lead to false data)

Any ideas/pointers

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what about:

```
var TestPlanSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    createdBy: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    testCases: [
        {
            testCase: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TestCase'},
            result: String
        }
    ],
    result: String,
});
```

You now may save additional info to each **TestCase** as part of **TestPlan**.

Comment: Will this break `.populate()`?